# Django - update model with user input by id

Tags: python, django

I stuck with my first app in Django.
Basically it will be several objects on webpage, every object with input form. If user types and email address to input, this object should be marked as 'reserved'.

I tried several solutions (and problably because of this multi-solution none of them worked). At the beggining I used AJAX to update the status of the object and it worked, but when I implemented email address input it failed. So I found out that I should give up on AJAX and go after ModelForm.

So for now my not-working code is looking like this:

```
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index),
url(r'^occupy/$', views.occupy, name='occupy'),

index.html
{% for gift in gifts %}
        <div class="panel-heading">
           <h2 class="panel-title"> {{ gift.name }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           {{ gift.link }}
           <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form }}
              <input type="submit" value="szukaj" name='q' data-id="{{ gift.id }}">
           </form>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

models.py
class Gift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, default='')
    occupied = models.BooleanField(default=0)

forms.py
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Gift
        fields = ('email',)

views.py
def index(request, id):
    gifts = Gift.objects.all()
    form_class = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        occupy(request)

def occupy(request):
    print('hrj')
    gift_id = request.GET.get('gift_id', None)
    if (gift_id):
        gift = Gift.objects.get(id=int(gift_id))
```

I guess that this parts are ok, but I am missing data flow (emails and ids).
Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? That when a user types his email into an input field, to reserve the object related to that input field ? If it's that it does look like AJAX is the good way to proceed. What exactly didn't work on AJAX ?

Comment: @PolRaguénès Yes, that's correct. So now my lack of knowledge is coming out - how to connect input (via form or just html input) with AJAX code.
My working AJAX to change the state of given object:
`$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/occupy/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            gift_id: element.attr("data-id")}
        success: function(response) {
            element.html(' ' + response);
        }
    });
});`